# Univariate cox regression in many subgroups (subsets) in R

Tags: survival, cox-model, forest-plot

I'm trying to perform univariate cox regression in many different subsets of my data frame. In order to give you a good example, I'll use here the colon dataset as a model.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
colon2 <- subset(colon, rx == "Lev+5FU" | rx == "Obs" )

OS_colon <- as.formula(paste('Surv(time, status) ~ rx'))

OS_surg0  <- coxph(OS_colon, data = subset(colon2, surg == 0))
OS_surg1  <- coxph(OS_colon, data = subset(colon2, surg == 1))
OS_perfor0 <- coxph(OS_colon, data = subset(colon2, perfor == 0))
OS_perfor1 <- coxph(OS_colon, data = subset(colon2, perfor == 1))

summary(OS_surg0)
summary(OS_perfor0)
summary(OS_perfor1)
```

My plan is to tabulate the "n", "number of events", "HR" (exp(coef)), "lower .95" and "upper .95" to create a forest plot afterwards. But as you can see, my code is too tedious and too repetitive as the number of subsets increases.

I've tried the following without success:

```
subgroups <- c('surg == 0', 'surg == 1',
               'perfor == 0', 'perfor == 1')

univ_subgroups <- sapply(subgroups, function(x) as.formula(paste('data = subset(dat,', x, ')', sep = " ")))

univ_models <- lapply(univ_subgroups, function(x){coxph(OS_colon, x)})
```

However, when I try to run the line with "univ_subgroups" I receive the following Warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: invalid formula "data = subset(dat, surg == 0 )": assignment is deprecated 
2: invalid formula "data = subset(dat, surg == 1 )": assignment is deprecated 
3: invalid formula "data = subset(dat, perfor == 0 )": assignment is deprecated 
4: invalid formula "data = subset(dat, perfor == 1 )": assignment is deprecated
```

I'm looking for a smart way to do that...

Answer (score 1):

The smart way to do this is to build your Cox model on all of your data first. Then get model predictions for predictor combinations of interest.

When you do subset analysis you necessarily lose power and put yourself at the mercy of small numbers of events in the subset. You lose the ability to draw on all of the data together to get the most precise estimates of outcome associations.

A Cox model also runs a risk of omitted-variable bias; that is, omitting any outcome-associated predictor can lead to bias in the estimates of coefficients for included predictors. It's generally best practice to start with as inclusive a model as you can without overfitting, then get specific predictions from it.

In R, you can use the `survfit()` function on your model, together with a dataframe representing the desired predictor combinations, to get estimated survival curves for display. You can similarly use the `predict()` function to get predicted risk scores, or survival probabilities at specified times, with standard errors.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a for-loop to do this, first, create placeholder objects to save your output

```
coefs = {}     
lcis = {}    
ucis = {}    
n = {}    
nevent = {}    
p = {}
```

Then run the model on data=data, for different levels in your subgroup-defining variable "subgroup" to get the risk associated with "var" i each subgroup.

```
`for(i in levels(factor(data$subgroup))) {    
  mod <- coxph(Surv(futime, event) ~ var, data=data, subset=subgroup==i)    
  coefs[i] = (exp(coef(mod)))
  lcis[i]  = exp(confint(mod))[1]
  ucis[i]  = exp(confint(mod))[2]    
  n[i]  = (summary(mod)$n)    
  nevent[i]  = (summary(mod)$nevent)    
  p[i] =  coef(summary(mod))[,5]    
}
```

And finally collect your output ( I rounded because I need to make a table - skip that if you are plotting).

`res <- round(cbind(coefs, lcis, ucis, n, nevent), 2)`